# Why is this global local Vue property undefined in the component during mounting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocha.js, karma-runner, vue-test-utils

I created a custom Vue plugin which creates a global property on Vue like this:

```
function (Vue, options) {
    Vue.$detector = new TranslatableStringDetector();
}
```

In my component I use it inside a computed property like this:

```
export default {
    // ...
    computed: {
        decoratedProfileName () {
            return this.$detector.decorate(this.$props.profileName);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

In the Karma/Mocha test I set it up like this:

```
before(() => {
            const localVue = createLocalVue();
            localVue.use(Vuex);
            localVue.use(TranslationDetector);

            store = new Vuex.Store(cloneDeep(storeDefinition));
            store.commit(SET_USER_DATA, userData);

            wrapper = shallowMount(Avatar, {
                localVue,
                store,
                propsData: {
                    id: 0,
                    inputElPrio: 2,
                    profileName: 'Default'
                }
            });
        });
```

The `shallowMount()` is what fails with the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in config.errorHandler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'decorate' of undefined"
TypeError: Cannot read property 'decorate' of undefined
    at VueComponent.decoratedProfileName (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:132143:35)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71415:25)
    at Watcher.evaluate (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71522:21)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as decoratedProfileName] (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71780:17)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:70216:20)
    at Proxy.render (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:180100:43)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:72817:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71061:21)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71415:25)
    at new Watcher (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71404:12)
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'decorate' of undefined"

found in

---> <Avatar> at src/components/controls/Avatar.vue
       <Root>
TypeError: Cannot read property 'decorate' of undefined
    at VueComponent.decoratedProfileName (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:132143:35)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71415:25)
    at Watcher.evaluate (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71522:21)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as decoratedProfileName] (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71780:17)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:70216:20)
    at Proxy.render (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:180100:43)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:72817:22)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71061:21)
    at Watcher.get (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71415:25)
    at new Watcher (http://localhost:9877/base/index.js?22adbcd7eb33d018f956122e913fca2646b1c60b:71404:12)
```

How is this possible? With `console.debug()` statements (Chrome broke debugging recently) I can confirm that `localVue.$detector` is correctly set up. Inside my component however it is not available as `this.$detector`. In example this results in "undefined":

```
export default {
    // ...
    created: function () {
        console.debug(this.$detector);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Being mislead by [the Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) I assumed "global" in the sense of a single object available to all components. Sticking to the documentation I actually wanted to have an "instance method" which indeed renders a property to all components. This is a small but important difference which solves the problem. I somehow tried and skipped that approach earlier when because something else was not working. The installation should look like this:

```
function (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$detector = new TranslatableStringDetector();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, use lambda functions ( anonymous function ) in the lifecycles hooks, will not work, due `this` have reference to parent object, which it is null.

use `function() { /*your code*/ }` instead.

Comment: I extended the component snippet. Do you mean inside the computed property or the Mocha test? I am not using `this` in the latter but in the former it has always worked everywhere in our application. Just my newly introduced plugin does not make it. It does not make a difference, if I rewrite the computed property.

Comment: Vuex remains available as ever via `this.$store`, if set up for the local Vue.

Comment: try to use Vue.use global and local, for test purpose.

Comment: As with `localVue` I can validate the presence of the assigned property on the original but it is not available inside the component. Apparently I have to dig into `shallowMount`…